# how to reapply changes from a branch to its parent branch

Tags: git

I was working on branch test1 with an open pull request, and then I created branch test2 and checked out to it from test1, so at this stage, the 2 branches were identical (I kept branch test1 as a backup).
After that I did several commits on branch test2, so now that my commits are final, I want to apply all the changes on branch test1, so they are identical.

what should I do in this case?

Comment: You could use a fast-foward merge? `git switch test1; git merge test2`.

Comment: is there other option if I dont want to use merge? I'monly use rebase I don't like using merge and I never use it

Comment: The `git rebase` command uses `git cherry-pick` to copy each commit that is being rebased, and `git cherry-pick` is, internally, a slightly weird kind of merge, so you've been using merge all along. Don't fear the merges! :-)

Comment: Why do you need to rebase? I don’t think that’d be helpful here.

Comment: If nothing new has been committed to `test1` after `test2` was created, `test1` is still parent of `test2`, and the merge as suggested by @evolutionxbox would be a fast forward anyway. You could also do `git rebase test2 test1`. It would just give you the same result.